# Tuple Concatenation in Chapel

Tags: tuples, concatenation, addition, hpc, chapel

Let's say I'm generating tuples and I want to concatenate them as they come. How do I do this? The following does element-wise addition:

if `ts = ("foo", "cat")`, `t = ("bar", "dog")`

`ts += t` gives `ts = ("foobar", "catdog")`,

but what I really want is `ts = (("foo","cat"),("bar","dog"))`.

So I guess the first question is "does Chapel support tuple concatention?", then "is there a binary operator/function for it?", then "if not, what is a good way to do it?", and lastly "make my life easier if you know a better way of living".

Please address the questions in order.

I appreciate the help!!

Comment: FWIW, I think renaming this issue "Tuple Concatenation..." rather than "Tuple Addition..." might make the title more precise and searchable, but I'm not eager to change it without your agreeing.

Comment: @Brad yep thats 

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> the first question is "does Chapel support tuple concatention?"

I believe the answer here is "no" for the following reason:  (1) A Chapel variable has a single static type that cannot change over its lifetime, and (2) a tuple's type is defined as its static number of elements as well as the type of each element.  Thus, given your variable `ts`

```
ts = ("foo", "cat")
```

its type is `2*string` ("a 2-tuple of strings") and this would prevent it from ever being able to store the value `(("foo","cat"),("bar","dog"))` since *its* type is `2*(2*string)` ("a 2-tuple of 2-tuples of strings").  So while these two tuples have the same number of elements (2), they differ in their element types ("string" vs. "2-tuple of string") and therefore aren't the same type (aren't compatible).

> "is there a binary operator/function for it?"

Due to the above, no.

> then "if not, what is a good way to do it?"

A few things come to mind, but may or may not be helpful depending on your specific situation.  Rather than trying to re-assign `ts`, you could create a new tuple that was a tuple-of-tuples:

```
const ts2 = (ts, t);
```

and you could even do this recursively in a routine, though that would likely end up blowing up your code size if the tuple grew to any significant length (because each call to the function would generate a tuple of a different type and unique code for it).

From what I'm seeing in your question, I think you may want to use a list of tuples or a 1D array (vector) of tuples.  Here's a list-based approach:

```
use List;

var listOfTups: list(2*string);

listOfTups.append(("foo", "cat"));
listOfTups.append(("bar", "dog"));

writeln(listOfTups);
```

And here's an array-based approach:

```
var arrOfTups: [1..0] 2*string;

arrOfTups.push_back(("foo", "cat"));
arrOfTups.push_back(("bar", "dog"));

writeln(arrOfTups);
```

Of the two, I would recommend the array-based approach because arrays are much more first-class and powerful in Chapel (they enjoy syntactic support, permit data parallelism, support promotion of scalar functions and operators, etc.) whereas lists are just a convenience library.

> and lastly "make my life easier if you know a better way of living".

One other related thing I can think of to mention if you're not aware of it is that "varargs" functions in Chapel effectively convert those arguments to tuples.  So given:

```
proc myFunc(x...) {
  writeln(x.type:string);
}

myFunc(("foo", "cat"), ("bar", "dog"));
```

the output is:

```
2*2*string
```

Comment: yeah that's what İ'd thought. similarly in Haskell, tuples are fixed length but İ'd been told that there was an append and the CDO package's `.execute()` method for postgres takes nested tuples instead of arrays of tuples so i thought maybe Chapel had some hidden magic somewhere that a newbie wouldn't know about immediately. @Brad

Comment: thanks for getting back so quickly by the way. I appreciate it :) @Brad

Comment: You're welcome.  I'm not at all familiar with the CDO package and its interfaces...  I wonder whether additional `.execute()` overloads could be added that would accept arrays of tuples?  Might be worth a feature request question against that package?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of forking it and submitting a PR for that